# Preg_match confusion

Tags: php, authentication, preg-match

While developing a login section , i got an error .

The result always shows up the false statement.what's wrong with this code

Could anyone guide me through "preg_match",Wolud like to know preg_match in detail.

The code is :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 {

if (preg_match('%^[A-Za-z0-9]\S{8,20}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['userid'])))) 
{
    $u = $_POST['userid'];
    echo $u.'<br />';
} 
else 
{
    $u = FALSE;
    echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please enter a valid User ID!</font></p>';
}

    if (preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z0-9]\S{8,20}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['password'])))) 
{
    $p =$_POST['password'];
    $p=sha1($p);
    echo $p;
} 
else 
{
    $p = FALSE;
    echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please enter a valid Password!</font></p>';
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you are entering usernames with atleast 9 characters ?

Comment: I don't exactly know preg_match in detail.Could you just explain it

Comment: @Peace Lover: Have you looked at the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?  If so, what confuses you within the documentation?

Comment: @Peace Lover:  Also, could you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know what does this meant by "%^[A-Za-z0-9]\S{8,20}$%"

And why i always getting the false statement

,Ie the else statement


Note: I have copied the preg_match search pattern from another file

Comment: `%^[A-Za-z0-9]\S{8,20}$%` is the regular expression that you're trying to match against.  Corbin's answer below outlines the parts of the regex.  There are plenty of regex tutorials out there.  A quick search on php.net brought up http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php (scroll to the bottom).

Comment: I got solution.It was my fault.I give length from 8 to 10 but i typed "peace" contains only 5 characters.So i reduced length from 8 to 3.

Thanks Jack Maney for spending time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%^[A-Za-z0-9]\S{8,20}$%

Means:

1 of A-Z or a-z or 0-9
8 through 20 of \S

I doubt that's what you meant?

Perhaps try the \S in the []

Comment: What is the goal?  What's the English description of what you're trying to do?

Comment: My aim is to resist the hacker attack through login

Comment: I got solution.It was my fault.I give length from 8 to 10 but i typed "peace" contains only 5 characters.So i reduced length from 8 to 3.
Thanks Corbin for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

In your username validator you only allow a single character. Put a length specifier behind the closing bracket, like you did in your password validator.

Why do you limit allowed characters in the password? The user should be able to use any special character he wants, and you also shouldn't limit the maximum length.

Comment: I have added the length specifier ,Still not work
It's for secure login

Comment: +1 for asking why there's an upper limit and no special characters allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably wanting something like the following:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

  # An array to capture and hold errors - makes testing for, and displaying them
  #  easier down the track.
  $errors = array();

  # First Sanitising of the Form Data
  $P = array_map( 'trim' , $_POST );

  # User ID Check
  if( !isset( $P['userid'] ) || $P['userid']=='' ){
    $errors['userid'] = 'Please enter your desired User ID of between 8 and 20 characters/digits (no spaces)';
  }elseif( !preg_match( '/[a-z0-9]{8,20}/i' , $P['userid'] ) ){
    $errors['userid'] = 'Your User ID must contain between 8 and 20 characters/digits (no spaces)';
  }

  # Password Check
  if( !isset( $P['password'] ) || $P['password']=='' ){
    $errors['password'] = 'Please enter a password of between 8 and 20 characters/digits (no spaces)';
  }elseif( !preg_match( '/[a-z0-9]{8,20}/i' , $P['userid'] ) ){
    $errors['password'] = 'Your Password must contain between 8 and 20 characters/digits (no spaces)';
  }

}

....

?><form>
User ID:
<?php echo ( isset( $errors['userid'] ) ? '<p><font color="red" size="+1">'.$errors['userid'].'</font></p>' : '' ); ?>
<input type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo ( isset( $P['userid'] ) ? $P['userid'] : '' ); ?>" /><br>
Password:
<?php echo ( isset( $errors['password'] ) ? '<p><font color="red" size="+1">'.$errors['password'].'</font></p>' : '' ); ?>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br>
```

The above will require a UserID and Password, each of between 8 and 20 characters (A to Z or 0 to 9).
If the form is submitted and found to fail the validation tests, the form is displayed with error messages near the fields which are not valid. It also includes the Username which was submitted (so the user can edit it as needed), but not the Password (as this is generally just not done).

Do a bit of a Google search for PHP Regular Expressions (there are plenty of tutorials and sites out there to help you learn more).

And also look at MD5 and SHA-1 hashing systems, which you should always use when storing passwords in a database - otherwise, like Sony, if someone compromises your system, they can see everyone's (probably reused) passwords and possibly compromise other accounts on other sites. (Not cool.)